# ajax returning search term and not full json

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Hi so I am using select2 to remotely get data and then a user can type a search string and it returns just the matched data

so far I have my ajax call within my select 2

```
ajax: {
            url: "data/more.json",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function (term, page) { // page is the one-based page number tracked by Select2
                return {
                    q: term, //search term
                    page_limit: 10, // page size
                    page: page // page number

                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {


                var more = (page * 10) < data.total;
                console.log(more);

                console.log(data.data.moreList);
                // notice we return the value of more so Select2 knows if more results can be loaded
                return {results: data.data.moreList, more: more};

            }
}
```

and here is the json file

```
{"data": {
        "moreList": [{
                "id": "1",
                "label": "Type",
                "jsonFile": "type.json"
        },{
                "id": "2",
                "label": "Primary Applicant Name",
                "jsonFile": "primary.json"
        },{
                "id": "3",
                "label": "Address",
                "jsonFile": "address.json"
        },{
                "id": "4",
                "label": "Product",
                "jsonFile": "product.json"
        },{
                "id": "5",
                "label": "Verification",
                "jsonFile": "verification.json"

        },{
                "id": "6",
                "label": "Documents",
                "jsonFile": "documents.json"
        },{
                "id": "7",
                "label": "Suburb",
                "jsonFile": "suburb.json"
        },{
                "id": "8",
                "label": "State",
                "jsonFile": "state.json"


        }]
    }
}
```

when i search at the moment it returns all the results within the json and not just the ones entered - I really just want it to show what is entered, if there are any results

if there is a better way of doing this, willing to do another way

obviously passing q is the way that rotten tomatoes have there api with out putted json setup

I will need to setup an api call eventually to make a server call and pass those variables but was wondering if I could just search a JSON file while prototyping

Cheers